# Copy data from one database into another using bash

Tags: sql, database, linux, bash

I need to copy data from one database into my own database, because i want to run it as a daily cronjob i prefer to have it in bash. I also need to store the values in variables so i can run various checks/validations on the values. This is what i got so far:

```
echo "SELECT * FROM table WHERE value='ABC' AND value2 IS NULL ORDER BY time" | mysql -u user -h ip db -p | sed 's/\t/,/g' | awk -F, '{print $3,$4,$5,$7 }' > Output  
cat Output | while read line
do
Value1=$(awk '{print "",$1}')
Value2=$(awk '{print "",$2}')
Value3=$(awk '{print "",$3}')
Value4=$(awk '{print "",$4}')
echo "INSERT INTO db (value1,value2,value3,value4,value5) VALUES($Value1,$Value2,'$Value3',$Value4,'n')" | mysql -u rb db -p
done
```

I get the data i need from the database  and store it in a new file seperated by spaces. Then i read the file line by line and store the values in variables, and last i run an insert query with the right varables.

I think something goes wrong while storing the values but i cant really figure out what goes wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `awk` used to get Value2, Value3 and Value4 does not get the input from `$line`. You can fix this as:

```
Value1=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')
Value2=$(echo $line | awk '{print $2}')
Value3=$(echo $line | awk '{print $3}')
Value4=$(echo $line | awk '{print $4}')
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to call `awk` four times in a loop. That could be very slow. If you don't need the temporary file "Output" for another reason then you don't need it at all - just pipe the output into the `while` loop. You may not need to use `sed` to change tabs into commas (you could use `tr`, by the way) since awk will split fields on tabs (and spaces) by default (unless your data contains spaces, but some of it seems not to).

```
echo "SELECT * FROM table WHERE value='ABC' AND value2 IS NULL ORDER BY time" | 
    mysql -u user -h ip db -p | 
    sed 's/\t/,/g' |                 # can this be eliminated?
    awk -F, '{print $3,$4,$5,$7 }' | # if you eliminate the previous line then omit the -F,
    while read line
    do
        tmparray=($line)
        Value1=${tmparray[0]}
        Value2=${tmparray[1]}
        Value3=${tmparray[2]}
        Value4=${tmparray[3]}
        echo "INSERT INTO predb (value1,value2,value3,value4,value5) VALUES($Value1,$Value2,'$Value3',$Value4,'n')" | mysql -u rb db -p
    done
```

That uses a temporary array to split the values out of the line. This is another way to do that:

```
        set -- $line
        Value1=$1
        Value2=$2
        Value3=$3
        Value4=$4
```